# Can't figure out error on PDO TRY code snipped

Tags: php, pdo, try-catch, fetch

The following piece of code is giving me this error

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on boolean" on
>   line 21

which is the line with `setFetchMode`.

Anyone have any idea what the issue might be? I can't work it out :(

Code:

```
 try {
 $query = $dbh->query("SELECT name, city FROM schools WHERE 1 GROUP BY name, 
 city");
 $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   //THIS IS LINE 21 error refers to
 $iterator = new IteratorIterator($query);
 foreach ($iterator as $row) {
 if (empty($row['name']) == false && !in_array($row['name'], $name_list))
        $name_list[] = $row['name'];
    if (empty($row['city']) == false && !in_array($row['city'], $city_list))
        $city_list[] = $row['city'];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try executing this code to see the error in PDO after which you can evaluate which part is to modify

```
$sql = "SELECT name, city FROM schools WHERE 1 GROUP BY name, 
city";
try {
   $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
   $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
     while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print $row[0] . "\t" . $row[1] . "\t" . $row[2] . "\n";
     }
 }
 catch (PDOException $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
  }
```

If this code fail, it will give you your error

Comment: I got the same error using your approach (Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on boolean).     Its says the error is in the same line as it was with my approach....the problem is in this line:    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

Comment: Maybe there is a way to write this in mysqli instead of PDO that will work instead?

Comment: Try writing it in prepared statement.

Comment: Just tried it. Still get "boolean" coming up in error. No matter what approach I take I get an error about something happening "on boolean". Still says: Fatal Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean. Why do both approaches keep giving this boolean error? The data type is not boolean.